# Is there a public resource for Adyen content security policy requirements?

Tags: adyen

I'm supporting internal teams within my organisation with Content Security Policy and Adyen has popped up in conversation.

I'd like to be able to refer to a public KB article or similar to help implement CSP correctly but have been unable to find anything public.

Not everyone involved in this project have an Adyen account so I can't check whether it exists but simply isn't public.

The [integration guide](https://docs.adyen.com/pt/development-resources/integration-security-guide/) refers to MDN. I was expecting an article on adyen.com tat I can refer to.